# fetch data with vue and sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, vue.js

I am using vuejs (CLI 3) with axios and sockets. My backend is NodeJs.

Html (view all users):

```
...
<ul v-if="users.length > 0">
  <li v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
     <router-link :to="'/oneuser/' + user.permalink" tag="li" active-class="active" @click.native="setmyid(user._id)">
        <a>{{ user.name }} - {{ user.last_name }}</a>
     </router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
...
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
export default {
  name: 'get-user',
  data () {
    return {
      users: [],
      socket: io('localhost:7000')
    }
  },
  methods: {
    mycall () {
      axios.get('http://localhost:7000/api/users')
        .then(res => {
          // console.log(res)
          const data = res.data
          const users = []
          for (let key in data) {
            const user = data[key]
            user.id = key
            users.push(user)
          }
          // console.log(users)
          this.users = users
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
  }
  mounted () {
    this.mycall()
    this.socket.on('user-deleted', function (data) {
      this.mycall()
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Html (user view):

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'one-user',
  data () {
    return {
      name: '',
      surname: '',
      id: localStorage.getItem('usId'),
      socket: io('localhost:7000')
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios.get('http://localhost:7000/api/get-user/' + this.id)
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data
        this.name = data.name
        this.surname = data.last_name
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  },
  methods: {
    mySubmit () {
      const formData = {
        _id: this.id
      }
      axios.post('http://localhost:7000/api/delete-user', formData)
        .then(this.$router.push({ name: 'get-user' }))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

backend NodeJs:

```
controller.postDeleteUser = function(req,res){        
    User.deleteOne({"_id" : req.body._id}, function(err){
        io.emit('user-deleted', req.body._id);
        res.send('ok');
    });    
};
```

When I go to user view and delete the user then it directs me to view all users. I have two major problems here.

1) After redirect, I saw again all the users even the deleted one. In my database the user has deleted correctly.

2) I don't know where exactly and how to use sockets in my code.

I am using in the front the socket.io-client npm plugin. Also I don't want to use (and I don't use it in my code) vue-socket.io because IE 11 and below version are not supported and it throws me some errors.

What I have tried so far:

1) Using watch like this:

```
watch: {
  users: function (newValue) {
    newValue = this.mycall()
  }
}
```

This is very bad for browser performance, because always call request from the browser.

2) use beforeUpdate or Updated life-cycle:

```
updated () {
 this.mycall()
}
```

That works but has bad performance. It makes requests many times to the server.

3) or that with sockets

```
updated () {     
 this.socket.on('user-deleted', function (data) {
   this.mycall()
 })
}
```

and that throws me an error:

```
this.mycall() is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?
Where to put the code with sockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the view all users file to:

```
...
methods: {
  mycall () {
    axios.get('http://localhost:7000/api/users')
     .then(res => {
       const data = res.data
       const users = []
       for (let key in data) {
         const user = data[key]
         user.id = key
         users.push(user)
       }
       this.users = users
     })
     .catch(error => console.log(error))
  },
  socketcall (thecall) {
    this.socket.on(thecall, (data) => {
      this.mycall()
    })
  }
}
....
created () {
  this.mycall()
},
mounted () {
  this.socketcall('user-deleted')
}
```

Life cycle-hooks cannot retrieved functions inside "this.socket.on" so I thought to do like above and it works!